# How to slice list in pythonic manner?

Tags: python, slice

I have the following input:

```
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.]
```

Expected output:

```
[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
```

Current code:

```
from numpy import linspace

input_list  = linspace(0,20,20, endpoint = False)
input_list[:5] = 0
input_list[15:] = 0
print(input_list)
```

I'm wondering if there are more elegant/pythonic ways of doing it?

Comment: There is `np.pad` but what you have is fine IMO.  Remove those semicolons.

Comment: Why do you believe your solution is not optimally *Pythonic*.

Comment: What are the rules/specs? Do you want the final list to be a specific size and the original list items *situated* in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, you could do this if you just wanted that range.

```
list(range(5,15))
```

Or if you want to ignore the first few:

```
[0]*5+input[5:15]+[0]*5
```

Or if it's conditionnal

```
[x if 4<x<15 else 0 for x in input ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a list inclusion:

```
l1 = [  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
15.  16.  17.  18.  19.]
l2 = [x for x in l1 if x in range(5, 15) else 0.]
```